# Can geometry nodes be used to dynamically measure face stretch in two dimensions?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I just discovered the Edge Vertices node (how did I miss this?) and suspect that it might be usable to measure stretch dynamically, something that I've wanted to do in Blender for a long time.

In other environments, I would measure face stretch from screen space derivatives, measuring change in UV over change in position, and comparing against some baseline.  This is a useful material value for several things, like outlining alpha-channel, deforming geometry (hair cards with physics), or for creating cloth materials with more pleasant UV distortion (cloth fibers that remain incompressible, while spaces between those fibers expand or contract.)

Even though I suspect this might be possible, I can't wrap my head around how to do it.  Each vertex is connected to more than one edge, and ideally, I would prefer to measure only edges aligned, more or less, with the UV tangent and output to one channel of a vector, and then measure the other edges, and output to a different channel of that vector, so that my materials could react based not just on overall stretch, but on the axis of that stretch.

This would be nicest as a face property, since it will be constant over a face, but a face corner property would be fine.  A point property wouldn't be as nice, but would be better than nothing.  I would be happy with any orthogonal dimensions, or even anything close, but U and V would be preferable.

Is this doable?  Anything close to it is doable?  How?

Comment: So the 'dimensions' you're after are U and V, as mapped ?

Comment: @RobinBetts I would be happy with any orthogonal dimensions, or even anything close, but U and V would be preferable.

Comment: That's kinda why I'm asking, just to clarify.. the _mapped_ UV dimensions would be orthogonal in UV space, but not on the mesh.

Comment: @RobinBetts Orthogonal on either UV space or mesh would be fine.  I'm not planning on using with crazy amounts of distortion, wouldn't expect it to be useful in those cases.  Any kind of answer is interesting to me, because even if I can't do what I want with it, I can learn from it and maybe do something I never even considered doing previously.